# Why can't I get selenium web driver to login to my Linkedin?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am playing around with Selenium to automate some Linkedin tasks and have this script below.

It successfully opens a chrome browser, opens Linkedin sales navigator, but then is not able to login.

I am using the correct cookies from my profile after logging in.

The chrome user that Selenium opens despite me pointing to a specific one, opens a user that says 'Person 2'.

Where am I going wrong?

This code below returns the following logs:

Adding li_at cookie...
Modifying JSESSIONID cookie value...
Deleting all existing cookies...
Re-adding modified cookies...
Navigating to LinkedIn with new cookies...
Checking if login was successful...
Login failed, please check the cookies again.
Login failed or driver is none

Note: I have removed my cookies from the script.

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)
import time, random
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import re,tqdm, json
import os
import datetime

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from seleniumwire import webdriver
from seleniumwire.utils import decode


def login(driver, li_at_value, JSESSIONID_value):
    try:
        print('Navigating to LinkedIn...')
        driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/sales/home")
        time.sleep(5)  # Waiting for the page to load
        print('Page loaded. Gathering current cookies...')
        
        cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        print('Found cookies:', cookies)
        
        print('Adding li_at cookie...')
        li_at = {
            'domain': '.www.linkedin.com',
            'expiry': 1691318269,
            'httpOnly': True,
            'name': 'li_at',
            'path': '/',
            'sameSite': 'None',
            'secure': True,
            'value': li_at_value
        }
        cookies.append(li_at)
        
        print('Modifying JSESSIONID cookie value...')
        for cookie in cookies:
            if cookie['name'] == 'JSESSIONID':
                cookie['value'] = JSESSIONID_value
        print('Deleting all existing cookies...')
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        
        print('Re-adding modified cookies...')
        for cookie in cookies:
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        
        print('Navigating to LinkedIn with new cookies...')
        driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/sales/home")
        time.sleep(5)  # Waiting for the page to load with new cookies
        
        print('Checking if login was successful...')
        header_items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "eah-header-item-content")

    except Exception as e:
        print('Login failed due to:', str(e))
        return

    if len(header_items) > 0:
        print('Login successful!')
    else:
        print('Login failed, please check the cookies again.')
        return

    return driver


def run(li_at_value, JSESSIONID_value):
    chrome_options = Options()
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")  # Point to the user-data directory
    chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 5")  # Selects specific profile with relevant cookies
    

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

    driver = login(driver, li_at_value, JSESSIONID_value)

    if driver:
        print(driver.page_source)  # Print the page source after the login attempt
    else:
        print('Login failed or driver is none')

        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
    #change your cookies in here!!!
            #make sure this value is up to date!!!
            li_at_value = ''
            JSESSIONID_value = ''
            run(li_at_value, JSESSIONID_value)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))
```

Comment: have you considered using a LinkedIn python API? e.g. https://github.com/tomquirk/linkedin-api

Comment: you see, there could be multiple reasons why the authentication doesn't work. they could be comparing the useragent that the cookie was created with to the one you authenticate with. or it has something to do with that 'li_at' cookie that's set to 
expire 10 days ago. ( 'expiry': 1691318269)